# Laravel : How to get values from table available in array?

Tags: php, laravel-5, laravel-collection

I am using laravel 5 and having following array:

```
    array:3 [▼
  0 => 3,
  1 => 4,
  2 => 5
]
```

Now i wanted to get all values/rows from table say 'X' having id's 3,4,5

Comment: Using a [whereIn()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.1/queries) perhaps? The Laravel documentation is there for you to read for yourself

Comment: Can you post your complete code pls ?

Comment: @Mark Baker Can't we use relations ?

Comment: What have relations got to do with this? Unless there's something you haven't said in your question, then this has nothing to do with relations, because you're talking about a single model (`X`), and simply retrieving values from that where the id is in your array

Comment: Your using of the words  "table" and "id" without any apparent relevant information on what that means is very confusing.

Answer (score 1):

Try this query

```
$array = [ 0 => 3,1 => 4, 2 => 5];

$results = DB::table('x')
                    ->whereIn('id',$array)
                    ->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

**You can see the query sample for Laravel 5**

```
  $result=DB::table('x')->whereIn('id',[3,4,5])->get();
```